# PDO Can't insert record contains apostrophe character

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting an error message while trying to insert a simple record to mysql database. I am using a simple PDO database class. As far as I know I don't need to escape the string for PDO. My database is set to utf-8

ERROR MESSAGE:
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

```
$user = $_POST["user"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$addUser = $db->execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_name`, `password`) VALUES ('$user', '$pass')");
```

I have this in my class:

```
function execute($query, $values = array())
{
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    if(is_array($values) && (sizeof($values) > 0))
    {
        foreach($values as $key=>$val)
        {

            $key = is_numeric($key) ? ($key + 1) : $key;
            $sth->bindValue($key,$val); 
        }
    }
    return $sth->execute();
}
```

Comment: try $db->execute("INSERT INTO users (user_name) VALUES ('$user')");

Comment: I also tried it but I'm getting same error message.

Comment: If you are using pdo, you should be using prepared statements, ie. `$user = $_POST["user"]; $addUser = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO \`users\` (\`user_name\`) VALUES (?)"); $addUser->execute(array($user));`. Using prepared statements allows you to not need to escape the string.

Comment: You are not using you function correctly. Try -> `$addUser = $db->execute("INSERT INTO \`users\` (\`user_name\`) VALUES (?)", array($user) );`

Comment: if you need to do more columns, it would be like -> `$addUser = $db->execute("INSERT INTO \`users\` (\`user_name\`, \`password\`) VALUES ( ?, ? )", array($user, $pass) );`. For each column you need to add, you add a placeholder `?` in the `VALUES()` and you add the value to the same position in the `, array(...)` portion of your function.

Comment: I see. So it's not very useful if I am going to have several columns. Maybe I should find another database class.

Comment: no, this is helpful class. This uses prepared statements, which helps to sanitize your query data. You just need to get used to separating your query and data, and not just directly injecting your user data into the query.